# Page as homepage of subdomain

Tags: .htaccess, subsites

I have View page like example.com/abc and I need to create subdomain abc.example.com that will show this page, but not like abc.example.com/abc.

I need to looks like it's the homepage of this subdomain.

How I can do this? Do I need some additional configuration on hosting or htaccess? What is the best way to go?

Comment: What exactly is your question? how change the homepage to abc? or how to create a sub domain? or both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Install and enable [domain](https://www.drupal.org/project/domain) module
2. Enable the submodule named **Domain Configuration**
3. Add a subdomain **abc.example.com** by clicking **Create domain**
4. Go to *admin/structure/domain/* and click on **edit domain** for abc.example.com
5. click the **Settings** tab
6. Set the value of the **Site frontpage** field to **abc**